# Eclipse C no output and I tried all the solutions on this forum and none works

Tags: eclipse, console, eclipse-cdt, output

I am having an issue with my Eclipse CDT not having output from console after successful building for C++ hello word program but it WORKS for C.

I have been googling all day trying to find the solutions but none of them works for me:
1. Change work space directory - my workspace is located at D:\workspace, so I believe the "space problem" does not apply here.
2. Switch 64-bit to 32-bit. Yeah, I tried both Java 64 bit + Eclipse 64 bit and Java 32 bit + Eclipse 32 bit. Doesn't work.
3. I also tried the Indigo package instead of Juno. Problem still persists.

Here is my current environment:
1. Win 7 64bit
2. MinGW (latest)
3. Java 64 bit
4. Eclipse CDT Indigo 64 bit

Anyone who could help me with the problem please? I am spending all day working on the issue.

Thank you!